# Retrieve Models with invalid Category Subcategory relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, pivot-table

I have three Models **Record**, **Category** and **Subcategory**. The Record table stores category_id and subcategory_id as foreign keys. There is a pivot table "category_subcategory".

I would like to retrieve all Records that have an "*invalid Category Subcategory relation*" in an elegant and performant way via a custom function in the Model.

What do I mean by "*invalid Category Subcategory relations*":

- **a)** Record has as Categroy and Subcategory. But the Subcategory doesn't belong to the Category (No entry in pivot table)
- **b)** Record has a Category but no Subcategory (subcategory_id = NULL). Because the Category itself has Subcategories, the subcategory_id of the Record should be NULL
- **c)** Record has a Category and a Subcategory, but the Cateory itself has no Subcategories, therefore the Record should have the subcategory_id = NULL

With this custom function in the Model I would like to be able to do sth like this in a Controller:

```
Records::withInvalidCategorySubcategoryRelation()->get(); //or similar
```

rather than going through endless foreach loops in the Controller like

```
$records = Record::all();
foreach($records as record){ ...
```

> Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Here are my Model Classes:

```
class Record extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function subcategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Subcategory::class);
    }

}
```

```
class Category extends Model
{

    public function subcategories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Subcategory::class);
    }

}
```

```
class Subcategory extends Model
{

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel offers `whereNotExists` that can be helpful here.

Add the following function to `Record` model:

```php
// Adjust the func name as per your test ;)
public function scopeInvalidRecords($query)
{
    return $query->whereNotExists(function($q) {
        $q->select(\DB::raw(1))
           ->from('category_subcategory')
           ->whereRaw('
              category_subcategory.category_id = records.category_id 
              AND 
              category_subcategory.subcategory_id = records.subcategory_id
           ');
    });
}
```

In Controller:

```php
Record::invalidRecords()->get();
// It'll give you all the invalid records(invalid as per your definition)
```

Hope it is helpful!

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion! You basically answered what I was asking for. But I figured out that I was unprecise about my definition of invalid Records vs valid Records. I have updated the description above. Would be great if you could extend the Model function to consider b) and c) as well. Cheers Tim

Comment: Since @Zeshan Khattak gave the decisive hint and was the most helpful I mark his answer as correct. Since I had not described my requirements sufficiently and later extended them, I have listed my final solution, which works and fulfills my updated requirements in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Zeshan Khattak I was able to get what I needed. Now I get the "invalid" Records where a) b) c) is met

```
    public function scopeInvalidRecords($query)
{

    return $query->whereExists(function($q) {
        $q->select(\DB::raw(1))
        ->from('category_subcategory')
        ->whereRaw('
            category_subcategory.category_id = records.category_id
        ');
        })->whereNotExists(function($q) {
            $q->select(\DB::raw(1))
            ->from('category_subcategory')
            ->whereRaw('
                category_subcategory.category_id = records.category_id
                AND
                category_subcategory.subcategory_id = records.subcategory_id
            ');
            })->orWhereNotExists(function($q) {
                $q->select(\DB::raw(1))
                ->from('category_subcategory')
                ->whereRaw('
                    category_subcategory.category_id = records.category_id
                ');
                })->whereNotNull('subcategory_id');
}
```